# Can ClojureScript's implementation of core.async be used in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

Is it possible to use ClojureScript's state machine-based implementation of core.async in Clojure, rather than Clojure's thread-based implementation? I'd like to be able to use core.async on the JVM but without using threads.

Comment: (go) implemented using state-machine in clj too. see doc for (go) and source https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/56ded53243e1ef32aec71715b1bfb2b85fdbdb6e/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async.clj#L356

Comment: Naturally, but I'm referring to ClojureScript's use of state machines in place of threads, not the Clojure implementation's absence of state machines.

Comment: I'm curious - why do you want to avoid using threads?

Comment: I'd like to use core.async on RoboVM for iOS development, but background threads can't operate on the UI.

Comment: You can "break out" back onto the main thread to operate on the UI using e.g. this function: [core.async/take!](http://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/take!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not currently possible, but there's nothing stopping you from modifying core.async to support a single threaded model. All the dispatching is handled via `clojure.core.async.impl.dispatch/run` Change that function to use some sort of other dispatch method, and things should just work. The ClojureScript version of core.async has a different version of `dispatch/run` that uses setTimeout (or other things that might be faster). Copy that code, and modify it to work on your VM and it shouldn't be that hard of a change.

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to use core.async on the JVM in a strictly single-threaded fashion, unless you're willing to reach into the internals and replace the threadpool used for `go`s with one that only uses a single thread.

However, as edbond points out in his comment, the Clojure version of core.async does use state machines for handling `go`s. These state machines are then run on threads from a thread pool whose size is limited to double the number of processors + 42, so it is possible to launch thousands of `go`s without using as many real threads.

The JVM core.async also provides a `thread` macro that works like `go`, but launches real threads, plus a collection of double-bang operations (`<!!`, `>!!` etc.) that work like their single-bang counterparts, but in a blocking fashion. Whether you use them is up to you; if you stick to `go` and the single-bang family of operations, core.async will never launch any threads beyond the above-mentioned threadpool limit.

Comment: At first, I thought `42` was a cute joke for the purposes of the answer, but then I checked [the code](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/76b25bf91c670b0c3542ed9cb687ff29fb2183a7/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async/impl/exec/threadpool.clj#L21) and saw it's a cute joke for real. :-)